# post css error on building project using npm build

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vite

[vite:css] [postcss] original.line and original.column are not numbers -- you probably meant to omit the original mapping entirely and only map the generated position. If so, pass null for the original mapping instead of an object with empty or null values.

```
error during build:
Error: [postcss] original.line and original.column are not numbers -- you probably meant to omit the original mapping entirely and only map the generated position. If so, pass null for the original mapping instead of an object with empty or null values.
    at SourceMapGenerator.SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping
```

i tried building project when it gives build error on postcss after debugging i find out how this imports is causing error:

```
@import "@material/button/dist/mdc.button.min.css";

/*material text box css*/
@import "@material/floating-label/dist/mdc.floating-label.min.css";
@import "@material/line-ripple/dist/mdc.line-ripple.min.css";
@import "@material/notched-outline/dist/mdc.notched-outline.min.css";
@import "@material/textfield/dist/mdc.textfield.min.css";

/*material checkbox & radio css*/
@import "@material/checkbox/dist/mdc.checkbox.min.css";
@import "@material/radio/dist/mdc.radio.min.css";
@import "@material/form-field/dist/mdc.form-field.min.css";

/*meterial data table */
@import "@material/icon-button/dist/mdc.icon-button.min.css";
@import "@material/data-table/dist/mdc.data-table.min.css";

/*material tabs */
@import "@material/tab-bar/dist/mdc.tab-bar.min.css";
@import "@material/tab-scroller/dist/mdc.tab-scroller.min.css";
@import "@material/tab-indicator/dist/mdc.tab-indicator.min.css";
@import "@material/tab/dist/mdc.tab.min.css";

/*material menu/dropdown */
@import "@material/list/dist/mdc.list.min.css";
@import "@material/menu-surface/dist/mdc.menu-surface.min.css";
@import "@material/menu/dist/mdc.menu.min.css";
@import "@material/select/dist/mdc.select.min.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to adjust your PostCSS configuration to omit the original mappings for these imports. Instead of passing an object with empty or null values for the original mapping, you can pass null explicitly.

Here's how you can modify your PostCSS configuration to handle this:

```
// postcss.config.js

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
    // Add a custom PostCSS plugin to handle the issue with original mappings
    'fix-postcss-source-mapping': function(css) {
      css.walkAtRules('import', rule => {
        if (rule.params.includes('@material')) {
          rule.params = rule.params.replace(/(original\s*:\s*\{[^{}]*?\})/g, 'null');
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: export default {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
};
here is my postcss.config.js

Comment: it gives this error:
[Failed to load PostCSS config: Failed to load PostCSS config
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/www/html/timemaster_bizkademy_com/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'path/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.

Comment: Rename your` postcss.config.js` file to `postcss.config.cjs` and Change your package.json to specify "type": "commonjs"

Comment: now it is giving me this error:
[Failed to load PostCSS config: Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: [Error] Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'fix-postcss-source-mapping'

Answer (score 0):

Might be this postcss bug:

https://github.com/postcss/postcss/issues/1914

Downgrading postcss may be one possible workaround.